# Взять изображение с url node js

Tags: node.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, данным способом я могу взять изображение с директории где находится код:

`const logo = path.join(__dirname, 'tux.png');`

Могу ли я взять изображение с помощью ссылки на внешний источник?
Пример кода:
https://github.com/song940/node-escpos/blob/v3/examples/image.js

Comment: Вам нужно скачать файл? или для чего это?

Comment: @MykolaKikets для печати изображение https://github.com/song940/node-escpos/blob/v3/examples/image.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких библиотеках очень страшно подставлять внешние ссилки... поскольку иногда может и не быть интернета, или обрыв соеденения...

Как решение можна скачать и распечатать...

Я привык использовать [download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download) для загрузки файлов

(Поверх примера)

```js
const save_path = "tmp/"; //Папка для сохранения файлов
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const download = require('download'); //Библиотека загрузки файлов
const escpos = require('../');

const device = new escpos.USB();
const printer = new escpos.Printer(device);
(async () => {
    var url_to_download = "http://example.com/images/logo.jpg"; //Ссилка для загрузки
    var name = path.basename(url_to_download); // достаем имя файла
    if(!fs.existsSync(save_path)) fs.mkdir(savepath,{recursive:true}); //Проверяем папку
    if(!fs.existsSync(save_path+'/'+name)||fs.statSync(save_path+'/'+name)["size"]<=0){ //Проверяем файл
        fs.writeFileSync(save_path+'/'+name, await download(url_to_download)) // если нет то загружаем
    } //Ну а дальше по стандарту...
    escpos.Image.load(save_path+'/'+name,function(image){
        device.open(function(){
            printer.align('ct')
                   .image(image, 's8')
                   .then(() => {
                       printer.cut().close();
                   });
        });
    });
})();
```